# Is there a tutorial on Scala 2.10's reflection API yet?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

Is there a good place to get a thorough tutorial of Scala 2.10's reflection API? I see lots of blog posts written over the course of the last two years, but many of the details of these posts are already out of date.

Now that 2.10 is publicly available, is there any document that will walk me through how reflection works?

Comment: This question should be re-opened, it is asking about facts: where are good sources to learn about Scala reflection.

Comment: @jhegedus No, it should not. Stack Overflow is explicitly not for recommendation requests.

Comment: Then what overflow is for that ?

Answer (score 17):

Check out the official reflection guide at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html. Thanks a lot to Heather Miller who took time to assemble it!

Other sources available are: 1) [the slides from one of my talks](http://scalamacros.org/talks/2012-04-28-MetaprogrammingInScala210.pdf), 2) [Daniel Sobral's blog posts](http://dcsobral.blogspot.ch/2012/08/json-serialization-with-reflection-in.html), 3) Scaladoc links on the stub pages accessible via the URL provided above, 4) and Stack Overflow answers. I might've missed something here, please let me know if that's the case.

Answer (score 7):

There are [these slides](http://scalamacros.org/talks/2012-04-28-MetaprogrammingInScala210.pdf) from Eugene Burmako, the principal behind reflection and macros in 2.10

Comment: Hey, folks... I love up-votes as much as the next guy, but you have a better answer from the horse's mouth... Up-vote Eugene's answer!!

Answer (score 2):

There is some links that come up when you search for it in the Scala Documentation site, but not much.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/search.html?q=reflection